# Secondary app dialogs or most of tooltps always pop up on secondary monitor. Is there a way to force them to primary?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, dialog

The first thing I need to mention is: this is Pop OS, but based on Ubuntu 20.04, so maybe someone could help here.

Basically, it's like on the attached image, with almost every secondary app window, as dialogs and tooltips showing up on the secondary monitor (right display is primary, that's where main application window is, left is secondary with application dialog). That's a little frustrating, left monitor is usually off, unless I do some coding work. Is there a workaround to this issue?

[image: annoying pop location]

Comment: Only Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Pop forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu & flavors are the many support options, you opted for Pop OS so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Comment: @guiverc you're right. i thought since it's Ubuntu based system it shares all pros and cons of Ubuntu. My bad. I asked that question again here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/646675/secondary-app-dialogs-or-most-of-tooltps-always-pop-up-on-secondary-monitor-is